# Return canvas that is drawed by some methods (plot, contour, imshow...)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wrote a matlab function that I try to return the graphics inside the figure.

```
function h = multifigures(I, f)
  imshow(I);
  hold on;
  h=contours(f, [0,0]);
  hold off;
end
```

I call this function inside another function, and try to save it to disk

```
function savefigures(I, f)
  h = multifigure(I,f);
  imwrite(h, 'sample.png');%or this-error saveas(h,'sample.png');
end
```

However, I just got a blank image (actualy, two rows of pixels).

Comment: I think you need to use the figure handle,f, not the plot handle, saveas(f,’sample.png’)

Comment: I commented there. This way is error!

Comment: You used the image handle, h, not the figure handle,f.